# Date Expression in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have written this, but it's not working:

```
=DateDiff("d",Fields!VDate.Value,CDate("31/03/2017"))
```

When I try this, it works:

```
=DateDiff("d",Fields!VDate.Value,Today())
```

What's wrong in my first `DateDiff`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is all about format `Fields!VDate.Value` formatted mm/dd/yyyy and `CDate("31/03/2017")` formatted dd/mm/yyyy ;) change `CDate("31/03/2017")` to `CDate("03/31/2017")` and  have fun.